# Google Play - one account, but downloading apps only on the first of two devices sharing the same account

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s-4, sony-xperia-z, multiple-devices

I have a phone - Samsung Galaxy S4 and a tablet Sony Xperia Z. Until now, I had a problem with Google Play - as I first set up Google Play account on my tablet using my email address, and later bought the phone and set it up there as well, I realized that if I wish to download app for my phone, it automatically downloads the app on my tablet, but not on my phone! All the other apps, like FB, Gmail, LinkedIn etc. are working on both devices using the same account, but Google Play automatically applies my commands to the tablet, even though I want to download the app for my phone.

I plan to buy Samsung S6 and I am wondering what to do about this as I feel I will have the same issue. I don't want to open the new account for the phone, as that would mean I have to change all of my other accounts, and I use this email address for so many years, at so many social networks.

I feel like an idiot, is there any answer why is this happening and where did I make a mistake?

Thanks guys!